# delete rows based in the value of the previous row in the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table:

```
LINE    CONTENT                    
245     Route selection data
365     To be continued...          
367     ---    END
373     Route selection data
424     ---    END
454     ---    END
462     PRA subscriber configuration
491     ---    END
545     ---    END
```

I need to delete the rows where content have the same values as the previous row, but I don't have to eliminate all the rows with the same value.
I need to keep the rows where the value of the CONTENT is different to the previous row.
In other word I need a table like this:

```
 LINE         CONTENT                    
    245     Route selection data
    365     To be continued...          
    367     ---    END
    373     Route selection data
    424     ---    END
    462     PRA subscriber configuration
    491     ---    END
```

I can't delete based on the value of the column line because the value of this column change everyday. I have to delete the records based on the values of the column content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple way would be to use a nested query with [`LAG`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm) to find duplicate lines, and delete them in an outer query;

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE line IN (
  SELECT CASE WHEN content = LAG(content) OVER (ORDER BY line) THEN line END r
  FROM mytable
);
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e11e0/1).

Comment: [`LAG`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm) is really an analytic function which is to be remembered! I took the liberty to add a link to the relevant documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach, assuming the `line` is unique:

```
delete from thistable
    where line not in (select min(line) from thistable group by content);
```